# How to use OR operator with wildcards while extracting files with tar

Tags: linux, shell, tar

While I can find all the .tgz files within a folder and then extract only PDF, EPUB and MOBI files from it if it is present in the archive.

```
find '/home/pi/Downloads/complete/' -type f -name "*.tgz"| while read i ; do tar -xvzf "$i" -C /home/pi/Downloads/complete/ebook/ --strip=1 --wildcards --no-anchored '*.pdf' '*.mobi' '*.epub'; done
```

This line of code works perfectly when either of pdf, mobi or epub is present in the archive. However with this code, whenever there is no pdf / epub / mobi within given archive it returns an error as shown below.

```
tar: *.pdf: Not found in archive
tar: *.mobi: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

How to prevent this error. I believe there should be a way to provide the multiple wildcards with a 'OR' operator as available in other scripting languages.

Comment: This is probably more on topic at http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://superuser.com, but I would guess that the wildcards will work like a glob pattern, and could be combined as `--no-anchored \*.{pdf,mobi,epub}` (but if none is present it may still report an error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tar` isn't a scripting language.

To hide the error message, just redirect the stderr of tar to a bit bucket:

```
tar ... 2> /dev/null
```

Note that you might miss other errors, though.

The safe way would be to list the files first, select the ones to extract, and only do that if there were any.

```
tar --list -f ...tgz | grep '\.\(pdf\|mobi\|epub\)$'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying with the following code but it is extracting all the files. `find '/home/pi/Downloads/complete/' -type f -name "*.tgz"| while read i ; do tar -kxvzf "$i" -C /home/pi/Downloads/complete/ebook/ | grep '\.\(pdf\|mobi\|epub\)$' ; done`

Comment: @Ankit: You should grep the `--list`, not the extract.

Comment: Ok. I get the list of matching files from all the archives but have no clue how to use it to extract listed files from archive. `find '/home/pi/Downloads/complete/' -type f -name "*.tgz"| while read i ; do tar --list –f "$i" | grep '\.\(pdf\|mobi\|epub\)$' ; done`

Comment: @Ankit: Pipe the list to `xargs` to extract the files form $i.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @choroba below code is perfect. No error reported. Posting the code as answer so that others have better visibility to the final working piece of code.

```
find '/home/pi/Downloads/complete/' -type f -name "*.tgz"| while read i ; do tar --list -f "$i" | grep '\.\(pdf\|mobi\|epub\)$' | while read -r line ; do  tar -kxvzf "$i" -C "/home/pi/Downloads/complete/ebook/" "$line" --strip=1;done; done;
```